jsPDF loadFile return an empty pdf
I have a code to load a PDF file from this URL.
 modify(fileData) {
    const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.loadFile(url, false, (data: string) => {
      doc.save("pdfjs.pdf");
      return data;
    });
  }

But the return from doc contains an empty PDF file. What should I do?
i can load my pdf file before

according to this issue you can not load and mondify external pdfs with this lib.

i have use pdf-lib before, it can modify pdf but can't set pdf permission, i think this lib can load pdf so I can move to use this lib:(
